# VSCode: ¿Es posible suprimir las advertencias del decorador experimental?

Tags: nodejs, vscode

En *VSCode*, aparece el error:

> El soporte experimental para decoradores es una característica que está sujeta a cambios en una versión futura. Especifique '--experimentalDecorators' para eliminar esta advertencia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi `tsconfig.json` tengo lo siguiente:

```js
  {
   "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": [
         "es5",
         "es6"
      ],
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "./build",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
   }
}
```

Y sigue sin funcionarme, ¿alguna manera de arreglarlo?

Comment: ¿Has probado a cerrar todos los editores y recargar la carpeta? A veces VS se queda un poco "tonto" a la hora de aplicar cambios en la configuración

Comment: @PabloLozano como estamos en un servidor no se como recargar todo

Comment: Puedes intentar alguna de las acciones propuestas en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271273/experimental-decorators-warning-in-typescript-compilation

Comment: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P` te llevará a la paleta de comandos, luego ejecutas `> Developer: Reload window` que usualmente es `Ctrl` + `R` y con eso recargas la ventana aunque a mí no me funciona el shortcut y le tengo que dar clic manualmente.